# webpack.config.js and vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am new to vue and I started a project from scratch.

I needed to install `vuetify`. However, I realized that I do not have `webpack.config.js` and `vue.config.js`.

Do I need to install it using `npm` or can I just directly make these config files manually?

Can help me how do I add this config files?

Comment: `vue.config.js` is a file you create, when the default config is not enough.

Comment: short anser manually

Answer (score 1):

If you created your app with the cli, until you want to add your custom config, you do not need to add those files.
If you need to add your custom configurations for webPack, you can manually create a `vue.config.js` and put there the setting for webPack, as explained [in detail here.](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html)